# Is it possible to reopen a closed app without user intervention?

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to remotely reopen a closed app on Android without the user's intervention. For those wondering if this is something shady: Every user voluntarliy accepts any permissions we request since it's an internal app for a limited community of users, and it doesn't need to be published on the Play Store.

Our goal is to be able to reopen it through a notification, alarm, or some external method without user's intervention.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does "reopen a closed app" mean?

Comment: To open a completed closed APP (not app in background)

Comment: Are you building your own Android firmware off of the AOSP to deploy to these devices?

Comment: No, we just built an app, not a firmware

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, starting an activity from the background is not supported on modern versions of Android. You are welcome to see if you can come up with something that [takes advantage of the allowed scenarios for background activity starts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

The polite thing to do is to raise a `Notification` and let the user reopen your UI at a time of the user's choosing, so you do not interrupt what they are doing at the time.

Comment: Our goal is to be able to open it without being in the foreground so the user doesn't notice.

Comment: @Juanjo: I have no idea what "open it without being in the foreground" even means.

Comment: We do not want it to open in the foreground so as not to interrupt the user. Is there a possibility of opening it in the background?

Comment: @Juanjo: You cannot open a UI in the background, if that is what you are asking. Even if you could, your process would become immediately eligible to be terminated, putting you right back where you started.